# NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE

Tags: java, gradle, findbugs

FindBugs is throwing `NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE` in the return statement of the below method. Tried to put null check for every value but I'm still unable to fix.

```
public String toString() {
   String filter = StringUtils.isBlank(this.filter) ? "NONE" : this.filter;

   String res = "";
   if (method != null && method.getName() != null){
      res = method.getName();
   }

   return res;
}
```

Comment: I see no attempts to check for nulls at the `7` different places you could get a `null`.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson  , updated the code.. getting same issue at the same line. can you help me?

Comment: BTW: there is s StringUtils.defaultIfBlank that simplifies the first line.

Answer (score 23):

Seems that FindBugs is not aware that two separate calls of the `getName()` return the same value (analyzing this would be quite hard). Seems that your `getName()` method actually sometimes returns null, so FindBugs internally marks this method return type as `@CheckForNull`. To remove warning call the method only once. For example like this:

```
String res = null;
if (method != null)
    res = method.getName();
if (res == null)
    res = "";
return res;
```